# How to fix "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list" Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want my function `getPlaylists(a,b,c)` to take values from lists a,b, and c and run until all elements in each list are used.

Specifically, I'd like to setup `getPlaylists(a,b,c)` so it runs `getPlaylists(a[0],b[0],c[0])` then `getPlaylists(a[1],b[1],c[1])` etc... until it completes all values in lists a,b, and c.

I have tried running `getPlaylists(a[0:],b[0:],c[0:])` and it gives me the error:

> "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

I have also tried running `getPlaylists(a[0],b[0],c[0])` followed by `getPlaylists(a[1],b[1],c[1])` in the following line. Only the first function prints successfully.

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials


def getPlaylists(a,b,c):
    client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=a, client_secret=b)
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

    playlists = sp.user_playlists(c)

    while playlists:
        for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
            print("%4d %s %s" % (i + 1 + playlists['offset'], playlist['uri'],  playlist['name']))
        if playlists['next']:
            playlists = sp.next(playlists)
        else:
            playlists = None
a= ["7ce6355bc7a34c659b6ce0b6a0c53395","a15e38973eb64f9bba30258a9dde407d"]
b= ["026081a8e1a544dbbcc2bf8a373f3088","8af7eaa281dc49a58d08e46adf06e637"]
c= ["121147088","20mc3a9w582vc7a7o5cjm03d8"]

getPlaylists(a[0:],b[0:],c[0:])
```

I expected all the playlists from each spotify account to print. However, when I format my code as I did above, I get the following errors:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/19083/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/SpotifyTest2_9.18.py", line 22, in <module>
>     getPlaylists(a[0:],b[0:],c[0:])
>   File "C:/Users/19083/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/SpotifyTest2_9.18.py", line 9, in getPlaylists
>     playlists = sp.user_playlists(c)
>   File "C:\Users\19083\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 366, in user_playlists
>     offset=offset)
>   File "C:\Users\19083\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 146, in _get
>     return self._internal_call('GET', url, payload, kwargs)
>   File "C:\Users\19083\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 100, in _internal_call
>     headers = self._auth_headers()
>   File "C:\Users\19083\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 90, in _auth_headers
>     token = self.client_credentials_manager.get_access_token()
>   File "C:\Users\19083\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 57, in get_access_token
>     token_info = self._request_access_token()
>   File "C:\Users\19083\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 67, in _request_access_token
>     auth_header = base64.b64encode(str(self.client_id + ':' + self.client_secret).encode())
> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
> ```

Comment: One of the downsides of the absence of type-checking is that you get errors like this instead of obvious type errors when you pass lists where strings are expected (e.g. the `client_id` and `client_secret` parameters to the `SpotifyClientCredentials` constructor)

Comment: @CraigMeier as far as I'm concerned the error is obvious enough xD

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
getPlaylists(a[0:],b[0:],c[0:])
```

`a[0:]` ([slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/41316)) means "return a sublist elements from list `a` from index `0` to the last item`- IOW, it returns a`list`(and in this case the whole list), not a single item. You want`a[0]` instead.

This being said, your data structure is wrong. Using "parallel lists" (2 or more lists where items are supposed to be matched by position) is brittle at best - reorder one of the list and the whole thing is broken... The proper structure here would be a list of tuples or dicts, ie:

```
clients = [
   # (client_id, client_secret, what_is_c)
   ("7ce6355bc7a34c659b6ce0b6a0c53395", "026081a8e1a544dbbcc2bf8a373f3088", "121147088"),
   # etc
   ]
```

which allow you to simply loop over it:

```
for a, b, c in clients:
    getPlaylists(a, b, c)
```

or using the the `*args` syntax:

```
for args in clients:
    getPlaylists(*args)
```

Also, do yourself a favour: **use meaningfull names**. `a`, `b` and `c` means nothing, and you have to lookup how those variables are used to find out what they are. Proper naming makes for more readable code:

```
def get_playlists(client_id, client_secret, whatever_is_c_we_dont_know_but_you_proably_do):
    # ...
```